# How to execute raw sql query with in entity framework?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-5, edmx

I'm using asp.net mvc 3 with entity framework 5. I have my .edmx file & able to interact with my database using linq or SP, but I want to run some raw sql statement. I'm trying something like this:

```
Using(var ctx=new HREntities())
{
  ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("insert into Employees values {0}, {1}",   model.EMPLOYEEID, model.EMPLOYEENAME);
  ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

is it possible to execute sql query this way? Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/915329/is-it-possible-to-run-native-sql-with-entity-framework

Comment: You might also have a look at my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16807334/execute-raw-sql-query-in-asp-net-mvc-database-first-mode/29147592#29147592


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16807334/execute-raw-sql-query-in-asp-net-mvc-database-first-mode/29147592#29147592

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can execute the following types of queries:

1. SQL query for entity types which returns particular types of entities.

   ```
   using (var ctx = new SchoolDBEntities())
    {

        var studentList = ctx.Students.SqlQuery("Select * from Student").ToList<Student>();

   }
   ```
2. SQL query for non-entity types which returns a primitive data type.

   ```
   using (var ctx = new  SchoolDBEntities())
   {

   var studentName = ctx.Students.SqlQuery("Select studentid, studentname 
       from Student where studentname='New Student1'").ToList();
   }


    //Error
    using (var ctx = new SchoolDBEntities())
    {                
        //this will throw an exception
        var studentName = ctx.Students.SqlQuery("Select studentid as id, studentname as name 
           from Student where studentname='New Student1'").ToList();
    }

    //SQL query for non-entity types:
     using (var ctx = new SchoolDBEntities())
     {
          //Get student name of string type
         string studentName = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<string>("Select studentname 
       from Student where studentid=1").FirstOrDefault<string>();
     }
   ```
3. Raw SQL commands to the database.

   ```
         using (var ctx = new SchoolDBEntities())
         {

              //Update command
              int noOfRowUpdated = ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Update student 
           set studentname ='changed student by command' where studentid=1");
             //Insert command
            int noOfRowInserted = ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("insert into student(studentname) 
           values('New Student')");
            //Delete command
            int noOfRowDeleted = ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("delete from student 
           where studentid=1");

          }
   ```

You can also refer [this](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/gilf/2009/11/25/execute-t-sql-statements-in-entity-framework-4/)

Comment: The second way is not limited to primitive type, and complex types containing primitive types also can be used here.

Answer (score 5):

This has worked!!

```
using (var ctx = new HR())
        {

            ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("insert into Employees values (9, 'Beverage')");

            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
```