# retrieving data from sql server using query in ASP.net MVC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am new to Asp.net MVC and I am also new to SQL server. I am able to write a long query with joins etc to retrieve the required data in MS SQL server. Now I want to display the query result in my MVC project as a new page. I dont want to use Linq because it will be another Big job to transform that sql query in Linq. I searched getdatafromquery() method but couldnt find any good examples. I am not even sure what I need to do to implement it. Can any one please let me know what will be the best way to achieve it. Thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So I achieved this by performing the following steps.

1. Create the sql-server query that you want to execute from C#.
2. In a controller create an ActionResult method for writing the query and connectionstring to the database.
3. Create a model that contains the same number of properties that is returned by the query
4. Create a view.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to use Entity Framework Code-First by following the steps mentioned on [Getting Started with Entity Framework 6 Database First using MVC 5](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/setting-up-database)

On the other hand, regarding to "retrieving data from sql server using query in ASP.net MVC" you might have a look at my answer on [Execute raw SQL query in ASP.NET MVC, database first mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16807334/execute-raw-sql-query-in-asp-net-mvc-database-first-mode/29147592#29147592)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am working on an existing project which is already using entity framework etc. The second part (your answer) is what I am looking for. I am trying to see if i can follow it.

Comment: You are welcome. But for the next projects, I strongly recommend to try EF Code First as it makes very easy performing the data field changes.

Comment: @Asbat If the answer is helpful for you, please do not forget to mark it as answer. Thanks...